Low speed brushless motor voltage feedback
A 4 poles brushless motor must spin at 527 rpm, which means each one of its 3 Hall sensors pulses at 17Hz. The STMicro L6235PD motor driver outputs 17 Hz PWM signal proportional to the speed.
To implement an effective speed control loop, I need a voltage signal proportional to the motor speed, with a fairly short setting time of less than 100 ms. So far I've excluded these options:

analog filtering with an RC the L6235PD PWM output signal, as suggested by the L6235PD datasheet, because it means very long setting times.
a digital PWM to voltage converter, like Analog LTC2644, because it requires at least an input frequency of 30 Hz.
Frequency to voltage converters like Microhip TC9400 or Texas LM2917, because they are +85°C maximum rated.

No microcontroller can be used; maximum temperature must be +125°C.
Is there any compact solution which avoids a lot of logic gates, flip flops, counters, etc.?

Sounds like you will also need feedback. Just supplying it with a fixed frequency will get you to that no-load speed, but with heavy load you may pull out of synchronous speed. Hve you looked for 125 degree rated MCUs?

You appear to be asking how to build a phase locked loop.   CD4046 can operate at 125°C  (and then I stopped looking)

A PLL was the first thing that came to my mind (like @JasenСлаваУкраїні) but just to confirm, does the signal from the driver change frequency with the speed?  You said it's PWM which might suggest it's a constant frequency and the pulse width changes with speed.  I'm guessing that's not what you meant, but ?
